# Python, path to library using Anaconda python IDE

Tags: python, path, anaconda, mechanize

i am trying to use the mechanize module for python on my windows 7, and i copied the folder to my path. "[..]\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\mechanize"

The problem is when i try to import mechanize, the path goes like "[..]\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mechanize-0.2.6.dev20161221-py3.5.egg\mechanize__init__.py"
"ImportError: No module named '_mechanize'"

But the correct path is: "\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\mechanize" and the init file is there, alongside with all others.

What should i do? please help :D

Comment: Looks like your setup is broken. Remove everything that looks like mechanize in site-packages and install it correctly using pip.

Comment: Before anything, thank you Fpbhb. I was getting crazy but i found my problem, it seems that mechanize only works for python 2.7 and lowers. I was trying to use with python 3.5 and i didn't even noted haha. My bad.